# Distinguishing which android button in an array of android buttons was clicked with buttons pointing to a single method

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, adt

As you can tell from this picture, I have multiple buttons set up in a keyboard style manner. I have each button's onClick in xml pointing to my btnKeyPress method. I plan on setting a switch/case for this method but wanted to know if v.getId is a very conventional way of differentiating between which button was pressed and wanting to know if there is a better way. I'm mainly worried about if v.getId will change or will stay constant according to my log no matter which phone the app is run on.

[image: screenshot]

For example: Here is my Space and Backspace key's XML attributes

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnKeySpace"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:onClick="btnKeyPress"
            android:text="Space" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnKeyBackspace"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="75"
            android:onClick="btnKeyPress"
            android:text="Bkspc" />
```

Here is what gets called

```
public void btnKeyPress(View v){
    System.out.println(v.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v.getId()` will always return the `android:id` set in your layout xml. So yes, you won't have problems if you use it to identify your buttons.-

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnKeySpace:
    break;
    case R.id.btnKeyBackspace:
    break;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Cool! My system out returned a number and was going to use numbers to set up my switch/case but didn't even realize i could set it up like that. Only been working with java for a week. I'm such a newb. Will accept this answer asap.

Comment: @GarrenFitzenreiter If you have a doubt, check the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId() It says that it's related with the `android:id attribute` =)

Comment: @ZouZou Thanks! Just starting to understand what all this means. I've only known vb6 for that past 12 years, so I get confused at times.